# How can I Format SOQL Time Range?

Tags: soql

How can I get data from a time range? For example:

```
SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE CreatedDate = 3pm to 3.30pm EST
```

Comment: Just so we're all on the same page, do you mean you want to find all records created between 3pm and 3:30pm no matter which day it is, or just between 3pm and 3:30pm on one specific day?

Comment: on a specific day/date

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, SOQL doesn't recognize "between", so you'll have to literally write it out:

```
SELECT Id 
FROM Account 
WHERE CreatedDate >= 2018-09-05T13:00:00.000-05:00 AND 
      CreatedDate <= 2018-09-05T13:30:00.000-05:00
```

Comment: Thank you, you have a script for merging bulk duplicated contacts? for some reason when the data loader restore contacts it also created duplicated and need a way to merge. Thx

Comment: @Feroze Unfortunately, no. A successful merge script usually needs to be tailored to the situation at hand. If I were going to do it, though, I'd set up Duplicate Rules, let Salesforce figure out the duplicates for me, and then write a script to merge the duplicates. That would be a far easier solution than writing customized queries every time.